# How do I initialize a complete class in C# with the PageObject model?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

as the pageFactory is deprecated in C#. I wonder how do I initialize classes on C#. I tried to call them by the `@Findby` and then call them on the Testcase, but I do not want to write 10thousend objects.

```
Pagafactory.Init = Deprecated
```

How to i initialize the Page objects where my webobject are

PageObject repository example:

```
     public class LoginPage {

        private IWebDriver driver;

        public IWebElement LP_Accountfld => driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#i0116"));
```

Test case:

```
public void Login (){ //LogIn TestCase

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Variables.URL);
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); 
            var Creator = new CreatorModel();
Creator.LP_Accountbtn.Click();
```

When I run the code, the variables are **empty**

Comment: LoginPage object initialization is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to handle initializing Objects is to not create them with [FindsBy...], but to create somthing like this its smoother and cleaner:

```
public IWebElement  LP_Accountbtn => _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#contentLogin > div:nth-child(1) > form:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > button:nth-child(1)"));
```

And you call it:

```
var Creator = new CreatorModel();
Creator.LP_Accountbtn.Click();
```

Comment: How do I call them in my Testcase?

Comment: oh right it needs to be public i will edit answer and you need to create instance of your model and then get it from there by dot like this:

Comment: if my answer resolved your question pls set it as an aswer ^^

Comment: Currently I'm just having the issue the "driver" does not exist in the current context. In wich library is this located

Comment: Okey so you have your PageModel in different class right ? Just create private IWebDriver _driver; Then in constructor create instance of this driver Chrome,Firefox etc. like this _driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), new ChromeOptions()); and then you can use _driver.<methodsFromDriver>. IWebDriver is from  OpenQA.Selenium;

Comment: ok I fixed it but i'm unable to initialize the class. I updated the code on the question for your reference. I appreciate very much your help

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the issue. I fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: No problem just can you set it as an answer that will help a lot ^^

Comment: Rajewski, 'ive implemente that correctly , but now when I run the  TC it says that "System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object." so I imaging that the Object is empty, I set Driver to the var Creator = new CreatorModel(); but another error appears, any idea?

Comment: Well do you have CreatorModel class anywhere ?

Comment: had to set up driver in the PO class

        public LoginPage(IWebDriver driver)
        {
            _driver = driver;
        }

        public IWebElement LP_Accountfld =>

Comment: Here have my github presentation project about selenium c# with Page Object Pattern, go to Shared Project and POM folder: https://github.com/JacekRatajewski/Selenium-CSharp-Presentation-POP